# Action when the small cross button of UITextField is pressed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I can add a small cross button that is used to clear all the text in a single click in a `UITextField` with the following code.

```
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

I also implemented `UITextFieldDelegate`.

I want to activate/deactivate the right bar button of the `UINavigationBar` according to the changes in my `UITextField`. The rule is simple: if the text field has at least one character, just enable the button, else disable it.

I implemented the `UITextField`'s delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` to constantly check the requirement and update the status of the button.

Now my problem is, when I click the small cross button on the text field, the method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` is not called. So the required action is missing. How can I identify the hit event of the clear button?

Some pictures to show what I'm talking about.

Initial stage: here, the "Done" button is disabled because there are no letters in the text field
[image]

When typing a letter, the "Done" button is enabled
[image]

Now, if I click on the clear button, the "Done" button is still enabled. This is wrong.
[image]

Comment: Please try this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60147293/10579134

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [delegate method `textViewShouldClear:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html):

> Asks the delegate if the text field’s current contents should be
>   removed.
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> textField
> ```
>
> The text field containing the text.
>
> Return Value
>
> `YES` if the text field’s contents should be cleared; otherwise, `NO`.
>
> Discussion
>
> The text field calls this method in response to the user pressing the
>   built-in clear button. (This button is not shown by default but can be
>   enabled by changing the value in the `clearButtonMode` property of the
>   text field.) This method is also called when editing begins and the
>   `clearsOnBeginEditing` property of the text field is set to `YES`.
>
> Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional. If it is
>   not present, the text is cleared as if this method had returned `YES`.
>   Availability
>
> ```
> * Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

Declared In
UITextField.h

Comment: Try this method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60147293/10579134

Answer (score 5):

You can use `textFieldShouldClear:` delegate method to handle when user taps on clear button.