# UISearchBar x button pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, uisearchbar

How handle the event when press the 'x' button?

I try this method but not works.

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

}
```

[image]

Comment: can you add the code for how you have allocated the search bar?

Comment: Check out [this](https://engineeringtheworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/detecting-when-clear-is-clicked-in-uisearchbar-x-button/) post

Comment: I have tried using the code but dont works in ios 8

Answer (score 45):

I don't think there's an easy way to hook into the X button.

However, you can hook into its direct consequence: cleared text.

Try this:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText == "" {
        print("UISearchBar.text cleared!")
    }
}
```

The side effect is this also gets called when you manually clear your text.

Comment: A more accurate description is that using this method to detect a clear button press is a hack. I can't believe Apple hasn't fixed this after all these years.

Comment: if it doesn't work, adding _ should do it. That is:  (_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)

Comment: With this you can't differentiate between deleting text with keyboard and pressing the x button

Answer (score 21):

A rather hacky way to do it but this works.

```
private var didTapDeleteKey = false

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,
               shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange,
               replacementText text: String) -> Bool
{
    didTapDeleteKey = text.isEmpty

    return true
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,
               textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    if !didTapDeleteKey && searchText.isEmpty {
        // Do something here
    }

    didTapDeleteKey = false
}
```

The success of this code hinges on the fact that when tapping the clear button of the search bar, `searchBar(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:) -> Bool` is not called. Instead when the delete button of the keyboard is tapped, the method is called.

Comment: hacking? Apple never realized people would want to tap that X?

Comment: the shouldChangeTextIn is not called when the X is pressed

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 5.2, Xcode 11.4**

This one worked for me.

```
if let searchTextField = self.categoriesSearchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField , let clearButton = searchTextField.value(forKey: "_clearButton")as? UIButton {

     clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.yourFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Comment: Where exactly should this code be used? I've been trying to clear the text field for days now!

Comment: @GuilhermeCrozariol , u can put this code anywhere like viewDidLoad() etc.

Comment: This relies on keypath "_clearButton" if Apple decides to change this key in the future, this will stop working.

Comment: Yeah...  till then maybe then will directly expose the button property.

Comment: This has to be best answer! Thanks Kedar

Answer (score 12):

As stated in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619594-textfieldshouldclear) there is a delegate method `textFieldShouldClear(_:)` in `UITextFieldDelegate`.

> The text field calls this method in response to the user pressing the built-in clear button.

So

1. conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`
2. set the delegate of your `searchBar`'s text field
3. implement `textFieldShouldClear(_:)` method

```swift
class MyClass: UITextFieldDelegate {
   weak var seachBar: UISearchBar!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          searchBar.searchTextField.delegate = self
       } else {
          searchBar.textField.delegate = self
       }
   }

   func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // your code
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Simplest solution in **Swift 5.0**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the docs in the header.... - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;   // called when text changes (including clear)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and it was solve like that:
In search controller that inherits from `UISearchController` I added conformance to `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Then in init method the following line was addd:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.delegate = self
```

And implementing

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

allows to achieve the information that clear button was pressed

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, tried to solve it with accessing searchBar's subview textField but it caused my app crash, and with a last effort i found this [post](http://www.codeitive.com/0SSWVqXUVe/fixed-strange-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-crash-happens-on-ios8-beta5.html).

Another issue was that,

`- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`

is being called twice when cancel button clicked, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160254/uisearchbars-cancel-and-clear-buttons-not-working-in-ios-7).

And lastly what i did is;

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (![searchText isEqualToString:self.searchText]) {
        self.searchText = searchText;
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Clear clicked");
}
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
self.mySearchBar.searchTextField.delegate = self

    extension myViewController: UISearchTextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.mySearchBar.searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest solution to this question is:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
     if searchText.isEmpty {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
             }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
-(UITextField*)getUITexfieldInUISearchBar:(UIView*)aSearchBar{
UITextField *searchBarTextField;
for (UIView *subView in [aSearchBar subviews]){
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)subView;
        [searchBarTextField setDelegate:self];
        break;

    }else if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
        [self getUITexfieldInUISearchBar:subView];
    }
}
  return searchBarTextField;
}
```

And you can use the TextFields Delegate

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
   //Do something here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
         //clear button (x) on the search bar is cliecked, so clear the table
        [self clearTable];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String){
    print("searchText: \(searchText)")
    if searchText.count > 0
    {
        // Show ur content
    }
    else
    {
        // Hide your content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

... just works

```
if(searchText.length==0||searchText==nil){
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(hideKeyboard)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}

- (void)hideKeyboard{
   [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until apple releases a proper delegate method for clear button event handling this will work as of Xcode 12. **Requires: >=iOS13**

*Get a reference to the searchBar `clearButton` if possible.*

```
UIButton *searchBarTextFieldClearButton = [self.searchBar.searchTextField valueForKey:@"_clearButton"];
if (searchBarTextFieldClearButton) {
    [searchBarTextFieldClearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(searchTextFieldClearButtonTapHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Swift:

```
extension UISearchTextField {
   var clearButton: UIButton? {
      return value(forKey: "_clearButton") as? UIButton
   }
}
searchBar.searchTextField.clearButton.addTarget(self, #selector(handler), .touchUpInside) //bllah
```

Very important to keep in mind that your "action - `searchTextFieldClearButtonTapHandler`" gets called last. That is, after the delegate method `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`

Answer (score -1):

You can hook up to "Cancel button" clicked event by conforming to "UISearchBarDelegate" and then implement "searchBarCancelButtonClicked" method

Comment: Nope, the cancel button is a different button which appears when setting `searchBar.showsCancelButton = true`.

Comment: Cancel button is different and "x" button is different. Did you check before posting if the "searchBarCancelButtonClicked" method is triggered on click of "x" button?

Answer (score -2):

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {


    let inputString = searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if inputString.characters.count > 0
    {

    }
    else
    {
          //Write code here for Clear button action
    }
}
```